# How are integrals on $\mathbb{R}$ defined?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

Let a continuous function $f : \mathbb{R \to R}$

Do we define $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(t)\,dt}$ as:
$$\text{1)}~~~\lim_{x \to \infty}{\int_{-x}^{x}{f(t)\,dt}}$$
Or as just:
$$\text{2)}~~~\int_{-\infty}^{0}{f(t)\,dt}~ + ~\int_{0}^{\infty}{f(t)\,dt} $$

If it's the second case, if $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f}$ is convergent, $\int_{0}^{\infty}f$ is also convergent.

If it's the first, we can say that if $f$ is odd, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f}$ is always convergent.

Comment: Most definitely 1) is *wrong*. That's called the Cauchy principal value. Yes, it's two independent limits, which is what 2) tells you to ask for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second. A few equivalent ways to write it:

- The limit of $F(a,b):=\int_a^b f(t)\,dt$ over the directed set $(\Bbb R^2,\preceq)$, where $(a,b)\preceq (c,d)\equiv a\le b\land c\ge b$
- The (extended) real number $L$ such that, for all sequences $a_n, b_n$ such that $a_n\to-\infty$ and $b_n\to \infty$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a_n}^{b_n} f(t)\,dt=L$.

Answer (score 0):

The second variant does not imply that if $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ converges, then the first sumand has to converge.

We can have the sum of two sequences converge without the sumands converging by themselves.

Comment: Well the second variant is not a limit, it implies that the result is defined only if the two sumands are defined

Comment: I would agree with you if it was
$$ \lim_{a\to\infty\\b\to -\infty}{\int_{b}^{0}{f(t)\,dt}~ + ~\int_{0}^{a}{f(t)\,dt} } $$

Comment: Since you work in the real numbers I don't think there is a well defined way of putting infinity in the boundary without referring to a sequence.